# Is it possible to determine if an element's height has been set explicitly through a style sheet or JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to be able to determine if a given element's height property has determined by a style sheet rule or JavaScript versus the size of it's content.

Comment: would that help ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you can't differentiate between inline styles and styles assigned by JavaScript code.

If the height is determined by a style sheet, the height won't be set on the element's own `style` object. But if code has set the height on the object explicitly (or it's been done with an inline `style="..."` on the element's markup), it will be there on `style`.

Example:

```js
const d1 = document.getElementById("d1");
const d2 = document.getElementById("d2");
const d3 = document.getElementById("d3");
d3.style.height = "20px";
console.log(`d1.style.height = "${d1.style.height}"`); // ""
console.log(`d2.style.height = "${d2.style.height}"`); // "20px"
console.log(`d3.style.height = "${d3.style.height}"`); // "20px"
```

```css
.d1 {
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="d1"></div>
<div id="d2" style="height: 20px"></div>
<div id="d3"></div>
```

Comment: So it is impossible to differentiate between height set by content and height set by the style sheet?

Comment: @h01001000 - As far as I know, yes. Setting properties on the `style` object actually updates the `style` attribute in the DOM.

Comment: @h01001000 what about (1) get the height value (2) set height to auto (3) get the height value again and compare with (1) ... if equal then the height is auto and no explicit height was set.

Comment: @TemaniAfif - That won't differentiate them though (the JS code vs. `style` attribute ones). You'll be setting `style="height: auto"` (in effect).

Comment: I will only set it for the comparaison in order to get the computed value of height when it's auto and if the computed value with auto is the same as the computed value without auto then there is probably no explicit height set,no?

Comment: @TemaniAfif - What problem are you trying to solve? The problem I thought you were trying to solve was to tell the difference between `d2` and `d3` above. I don't think it would do that, but maybe I've misunderstood what you're trying to do?

Comment: it's not about your code but the question. My idea to know if there is an explicit height set is to compare two values. The first value we get with computedStyle and the second value we also get with computedStyle after setting the height to auto ... if both are equal then (I guess) we don't have any explicit height. If not, then for sure there is a height set.

Comment: @TemaniAfif - Ah, okay. Yeah, I think that would work. It would have the same `d2`/`d3` problem the above does, though, and would involve modifying the display (briefly).

Comment: @TemaniAfif Cool idea!  It gets the job done, thank you!  I will still be on the hunt for a less invasive way to accomplish this but for now this will do.

Comment: @h01001000 - I don't understand, there's no need for writing `auto`. The answer above should be sufficient...? Is there something I'm missing?